# FlatList set ViewabilityConfig in an functional component

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have this functional component, and now i want to configure the viewabilityConfig, but when i try to scroll my list i get this error:

```js
[Unhandled promise rejection: Invariant Violation: Must set exactly one of itemVisiblePercentThreshold or viewAreaCoveragePercentThreshold]
```

I have tried to put the config into an useRef but that would trigger the same error.

```js
    export default function Test(){
 
        const _viewabilityConfig = {
            minimumViewTime: 50,
            waitForInteraction: true,
            viewAreaCoveragePercentThreshold: 100,
            itemVisiblePercentThreshold: 80
        }
        
        return(
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <FlatList
                    data={dataSource}
                    viewabilityConfig={_viewabilityConfig}
                    onViewableItemsChanged={onViewRef.current}
                    ItemSeparatorComponent={renderSeperator}
                    ref={flatListRef}
                />
            </View>
        )
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const _viewabilityConfig = useRef({
viewAreaCoveragePercentThreshold: 60});
```

and in flatlist

`viewabilityConfig={_viewabilityConfig.current}`

Comment: I suggest to explain better why the question submitter was wrong and how your answer does the correct thing.

Answer (score 0):

I could fix the issue by using this config

```
        const _viewabilityConfig = {
            minimumViewTime: 50,
            viewAreaCoveragePercentThreshold: 100,
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Why do you need both itemVisiblePercentThreshold and viewAreaCoveragePercentThreshold?

Remove one of the properties and try.

See [this](https://reactnative.dev/docs/0.55/flatlist#viewabilityconfig) to know what exactly you want.

Comment: tihs pages is not found